# findViewById not working with ids created using View.generateViewId

Tags: android, kotlin, dynamic-view

I'm trying to access a view with a dynamically created id, using `findViewById` but it always returns `null`.

This is how I'm creating the id, using `View.generateViewId()` and `ViewCompat.generateViewId()` for lower API versions.

```
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import android.view.View

...
// generate an id
val id = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    View.generateViewId()
} else {
    ViewCompat.generateViewId()
}
// assign the id
view.id = id
// Then add it to a parent view
parent.addView(view)
...
```

Logging the id gives `3`.

Now, the view is getting created, it is visible, there are no errors and even the layout inspector shows the id assigned by the `View.generateViewId()` to be `0x3` i.e. `3`.

[image: image_bruh]

```
val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(id)
```

But the `layout` is always `null`.

`findViewById` returns the `LinearLayout` successfully when given an id that's defined in `ids.xml` or the `layout/....xml`.

It fails only with dynamically created ids.

Comment: Try using `val layout = parent.findViewById<LinearLayout>(id)`

Comment: I slightly simplified it for asking the question but I don't have access to the `parent` the `parent` is a local variable in a view pager adapter.

Comment: I tried `viewPager.findViewById<LinearLayout>(id)` but it returns `null` aswell

Comment: Why don't you save the reference to the view instead of saving your id?

Comment: Should I save a reference to all my views that I'm adding in a `viewpager` won't they get re-created?